# Path to shell executable not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, g++

I have configured g++/gdb and VSCode on my computer as per a class, however I have been getting a strange error when attempting to Run/Debug a task. In the VSCode terminal it outputs

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "cmd.exe" does not exist.
```

In my PATH, I added cmd.exe to it thinking that would fix it, but to no avail. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it? Thank you!
[PATH Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFymi.png)

Comment: `PATH` should _not_ point to `cmd.exe`, but to a _directory_ containing it.

Comment: Are you referring to where VSCode's settings.json points to a PATH or in the actual PATH environment variable itself?

Comment: Both. All the other entries in your VSCode image are directories.